# Как добавить кастомные утверждения в токен azure b2c с помощью коннекторов api и веб-api asp net core

Tags: c#, active-directory, azure

У меня есть пользовательский поток B2C_1_singupsingin1
Я добавил api connector, встроил его в этот поток и указал URL-адрес конечной точки для вызова API.
Использовал статью
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-api-connector-token-enrichment?pivots=b2c-user-flow

Из статьи понятно, что коннектор API материализуется как HTTP- запрос POST , отправляя пользовательские атрибуты.

В моем веб апи есть конечная точка с кодом:

```
[HttpPost("enrich")]
public IActionResult Enrich([FromBody] JsonElement body)
{
    var responseProperties = new Dictionary<string, object> //for example
    {
        { "version", "1.0.0" },
        { "action", "Continue" },
        { "postalCode", "12349" },
        { "userId", 123 } 
    };

    return new JsonResult(responseProperties) { StatusCode = 200 };
}
```

Когда я запускаю пользовательский поток, все работает, я попадаю в эту конечную точку в апи.
Но есть проблема JsonElement body не содержит пользовательских атрибутов. Внутри я вижу `body.ValueKind = Undefined`.
Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Так же, после всего, я хотел бы добавить кастомное утверждение "userId" с каким-то значением из моей базы данных.
Чтобы оно содержалось в выпущенном в последствии токене. Будет ли код выше правильным, для этого?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему давно, но может мой опыт кому-то поможет.
Первая часть вопроса:

> JsonElement body не содержит пользовательских атрибутов. Внутри я вижу
> body.ValueKind = Undefined.

В чем была проблема.
Для поддержки запросов HTTP Patch я добавил в Startup пакет и конфигурацию NewtonsoftJson:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(x => 
{
   x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```

Но я не учел, что AddNewtonsoftJson заменяет основанные на System.Text.Json средства форматирования ввода и вывода, используемые для форматирования всего содержимого JSON. Из-за этого у меня возникла вышеуказанная проблема. [Решение из документации microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

По второй части вопроса. Для добавления кастомного утверждения, вы просто должны добавить **extension_** префикс к утверждению.